# Is it possible to add dependencies to sublime-extensions?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm building a sublime extension that imports git from sublimeGit:

```
import git
```

I do it to define what git repo and branch I am in etc.

Is this suitable and in that case, can you define the dependency somehow in the plugin. to let package-manager etc know that this won't work without git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define dependecies for PackageControll by putting file

```
dependencies.json
```

to extension/plugin/Package directory.

See bottom of [PackageControl docs](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `git` module is installed, you can import it in your own plugin code. However, there is no way currently to define dependencies in Package Control, other than putting a great big notice in your README and `messages.json` file that it's required for proper functioning of your plugin.